# Using country-region-selector plugin with dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-plugins

I'm using the country-region-selector javascript plugin to create comprehensive region/dropdown menus in an app.  The particular application that I'm working on is for completing the addresses of a list of people.  The challenge is that this list is dynamically generated (I'm using rails and the cocoon gem on the backend but that's probably not terribly important).  There are workarounds from the documentation though, which involves creating ids and populating the list on the fly; all of this is very clear and seems to be working.

**The issue is** that when I load the list form my database, the FIRST person's country and region loads without a problem.  However, for all subsequent people, the country menu loads but the state menu does NOT.  Fortunately, I have been able to replicate this exact problem in a jsfiddle, leading me to believe that I must be doing something objectively wrong.  To clarify, it does not seem to be an intrinsic issue with the fields themselves.  There are three in the fiddle; if I get rid of the first person, the (formerly) second person then works but the (formerly) third still does not.  More peculiar still, is that I do have another region/country field in the app that has nothing to do with the person fields but appears above them and it works fine, along with the first person.  You can find the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/neanderslob/tLw5sa77/6/) and the plugin itself, with documentation [here](https://github.com/benkeen/country-region-selector).

The rest of the content of the question is essentially an appendix so I'll say now, thanks for any suggestions.

### Appendix

**The basic "how to use" of the plugin is as follows**

> How to Use
>
> It's very easy.
>
> 1)  Include the crs.min.js file in your webpage.
>
> 2)  Add two `<select>` fields in the appropriate locations in your form.
>
> 3)  Give the country field a class of crs-country.
>   4)  Now we need to map each country field to its corresponding region field so the script knows what to update when a country is selected. Add an attribute to the country dropdown: data-region-id="ABC" where ABC is any string. Now Give the region dropdown an id of "ABC".
>
> That's it! You're done.

**Here's an example of one of the people for whom it's not working:**

```
<div class="clearfix entity-add nested-fields person">
<div class="dynamic-container">
    <div class="symegrid">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="input string optional company_people_fname">
                <label class="string optional" for="company_people_attributes_2_fname">First Name</label>
                <input class="string optional fname form-input form-control fifty" type="text" value="test" name="company[people_attributes][2][fname]" id="company_people_attributes_2_fname" />
            </div>
            <div class="input string optional company_people_lname">
                <label class="string optional" for="company_people_attributes_2_lname">Last Name</label>
                <input class="string optional lname form-input form-control fifty" type="text" value="1" name="company[people_attributes][2][lname]" id="company_people_attributes_2_lname" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="input email optional company_people_email">
                <label class="email optional" for="company_people_attributes_2_email">Email</label>
                <input class="string email optional email form-input form-control" type="email" value="2" name="company[people_attributes][2][email]" id="company_people_attributes_2_email" />
            </div>
            <div class="input tel optional company_people_telephone">
                <label class="tel optional" for="company_people_attributes_2_telephone">Telephone</label>
                <input class="string tel optional telephone form-input form-control" type="tel" value="3" name="company[people_attributes][2][telephone]" id="company_people_attributes_2_telephone" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="input string optional company_people_street">
                <label class="string optional" for="company_people_attributes_2_street">Street</label>
                <input class="string optional street form-input form-control" type="text" value="" name="company[people_attributes][2][street]" id="company_people_attributes_2_street" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="input string optional company_people_city">
                <label class="string optional" for="company_people_attributes_2_city">City</label>
                <input class="string optional city form-input form-control" type="text" value="" name="company[people_attributes][2][city]" id="company_people_attributes_2_city" />
            </div>
            <div class="input select optional company_people_country">
                <label class="select optional" for="company_people_attributes_2_country">Country</label>
                <select data-region-id="person_state" data-default-value="United States" class="select optional location country form_control crs-country" name="company[people_attributes][2][country]" id="company_people_attributes_2_country">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="true">Yes</option>
                    <option value="false">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="input select optional company_people_state">
                <label class="select optional" for="person_state">State/Province</label>
                <select id="person_state" class="select optional state form-control location crs-state" data-default-value="Utah" name="company[people_attributes][2][state]">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="true">Yes</option>
                    <option value="false">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input string optional company_people_zip">
                <label class="string optional" for="company_people_attributes_2_zip">Zip</label>
                <input class="string optional zip form-input form-control" type="text" value="" name="company[people_attributes][2][zip]" id="company_people_attributes_2_zip" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data-region-id you are applying to attr doesn't get written to the dom.

When you change properties on jquery the real element on the website doesn't change, just the stored element on "jquery space" chanhges.
That's why the init() of your plugin does not work.

To work arround that you need to alter the html with

```
 //pseudo pseudo code
 $('selector').html('<select data-region-id="something'+index+'"></select')
```

or similar.

In case it helps you in any way I discovered this doing the following:

1. on the first field choose a country and a region
2. on the second field change the country
3. See that it ressets the region on the first field

I assume that's because It's not being able to tell the different selectors apart.

Comment: Nailed it.  I couldn't get the `.html()` to work (I'm sure I was making an error of some sort) but I solved the issue server-side with your explanation.  THANK YOU.  I have spent HOURS on this.